# Insert an XML parent node to an existing xml document

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sharepoint, xml-parsing

I have an XML document. I am trying to add a parent node to the xml document dynamically. How do i do.

Here is my xml

```
  <navdefinition>
  <link text="/and" href="/and">
      <link text="Overview" href="/overview"  />
      <link text="Information" href="/fo"/>        
  </link>
  </navdefinition>
```

I am trying to add node to top of this so that one will be the new parent and one sibling at top

```
    <navdefinition>
      <link text="NewParent" href="/">
         <link text="Sibling" href="/sibling"/>
         <link text="/and" href="/and">
             <link text="Overview" href="/overview"  />
             <link text="Information" href="/fo"/>
         </link>
      </link>
  </navdefinition>
```

Comment: I see you have not written the actual code to process the input XML. Don't look at the answers now. I'm sure you can do this yourself. Then look at the answers if they can be used :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication82
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<navdefinition>" +
                  "<link text=\"/and\" href=\"/and\">" +
                      "<link text=\"Overview\" href=\"/overview\"  />" +
                      "<link text=\"Information\" href=\"/fo\"/>" +
                  "</link>" +
                "</navdefinition>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement navDefinition = doc.Element("navdefinition");
            navDefinition.FirstNode.ReplaceWith(
                new XElement("link", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("text", "NewParent"),
                    new XAttribute("href", "/"),
                    new XElement("link", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("text", "Sibling"),
                        new XAttribute("href", "/sibling"),
                        navDefinition.FirstNode
                    })
                })
            );

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new parent XElement and set its child content:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var parentElement = new XElement("link", xmlDoc.Root.Elements());
parentElement.SetAttributeValue("text", "NewParent");
parentElement.SetAttributeValue("href", "/");
xmlDoc.Root.ReplaceNodes(parentElement);
```